# Coloring/indenting a script within script in Emacs

Tags: bash, emacs, awk, text-indent, text-coloring

I often have shell scripts that call other scripting languages, like so:

```
#!/bin/bash
cat somefile|awk '
BEGIN
{
  #This line is not auto-indented and is colored as a string constant.
  ...
}
{
  #Same with this line.
  ...
}'

echo "More Bash code here."
...
```

Is there a way to make Emacs recognize the awk string as an awk program instead of just a string constant?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to make your own extensions to your existing emacs lisp files.  Here is a helpful tutorial on learning emacs lisp:
http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/emacs-lisp-intro/

And here is an example of an .el file that colors html:
http://fly.srk.fer.hr/~hniksic/emacs/htmlize.el

Once you're done, post it online so others can benefit!

Answer (score 1):

I use [mmm-mode](http://mmm-mode.sourceforge.net/) for [Mason](http://masonhq.com/) files (mixing HTML and Perl); maybe it can be of use in your case as well?